# boto3 get tenancy value from placement gives name error

Tags: python-3.x, boto3

Trying to make a script that gathers info about our AWS environment.  I want to get just the tenancy info from the placement.

Using the client in boto3 i have tried the to get the placement[Tenancy] but i get error

> NameError: name 'Tenancy' is not defined.

I have also tried to loop through and get just the key value if it matches but im getting

> if 'tenancy' in n['key']:
>   TypeError: string indices must be integers

Here is what i am currently thinking should return just the tenancy if it exsists.

```
for i in client.instances.all():
    for n in i.placement:
        if 'tenancy' in n['Key']:
            tenancy = n['Value']
```

I just want to get the tenancy returned if it's on host default etc.  Not sure why i cant get the placement dictionary to print just the value.

Comment: You are using `resource` not `client` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented, you are using boto3 `resource` not `client`. Just make for sure. In order to get the Tenancy of instance, do this.

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

response = ec2.instances.all()
for item in response:
    print(item.placement.get('Tenancy'))
```

Comment: Thanks i am using resource.  For whatever reason i thought i was using the client actions.  Thanks that helps.